# How to enable display of Matplotlib graphs with PyCharm?

Tags: matplotlib, pycharm

When I run a program with PyCharm, it doesn't display graphs made with Matplotlib. E.g.:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
[...]
plt.imshow(montage(W / np.max(W)), cmap='coolwarm')
```

I tried calling

```
plt.interactive(False)
```

first, but it didn't make a difference.

Running the same program with ipython3, the graphs are displayed.

Comment: There is a setting someplace deep in the options to select the matplotlib backend to use.  Make sure it is set to qt4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set a [default back-end](https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend) for my system in matplotlibrc (TkAgg), and that did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

The below code worked for me:

```
in pycharm-community-2018.2.2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df.boxplot(column='ApplicantIncome')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer so it is better understood!